# loaded data is not showing when ngModel is using Angular8

Tags: html, angular, typescript, angular8

Initially when I used `{{item.name}}` to load the value it worked perfectly, but after I added `ngModel` it stopped working properly. Now no value is showing and whenever I enter anything in one text box the other text boxes also get filled with the same value

please help me to solve this,

**HTML Code**

```html
<tr *ngFor="let item of this.familyInfo">
  <td><input type="text" class="form-control" value="{{item.name | titlecase}}" [(ngModel)]="this.cr.name"></td>
  <td><input type="text" class="form-control" value="{{item.age}}" [(ngModel)]="this.cr.age"></td>
  <td><input type="text" class="form-control" value="{{item.relation | titlecase}}" [(ngModel)]="this.cr.relation"></td>
  <td><button class="style_blue_button_square" style="width: 100%;" id={{item.id}}
      (click)="updateFamilyInfo($event)">Udate</button></td>
</tr>
```

Answer (score 0):

you need to add "FormsModule" to your app.module.ts file

```
import { BrowserModule } from '@angular/platform-browser';
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';

import { AppComponent } from './app.component';
import {FormsModule} from '@angular/forms';

@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    AppComponent,
  ],
  imports: [
    BrowserModule,
    FormsModule
  ],
  providers: [],
  bootstrap: [AppComponent]
})
export class AppModule { }
```

I reviewed you the above code, too.

```
[(ngModel)]="this.cr.name"
```

at there, **this.** was wrong. "this." don't need. you need to fix like the following.

```
[(ngModel)]="cr.name"
```

Comment: alrdy added...  `FormsModule` to `app.module.ts`

Comment: I reviewed your the above code again. [(ngModel)]="this.cr.name" at here, you don't need "this." [(ngModel)]="cr.name" will work for you :)

Answer (score 0):

When using ngModel, you don’t need to bind to value, ngModel does that for you. Perhaps this combination is causing the trouble?

Comment: Yes.. It's not working properly.. And entered value in one textbox is replaced to others

Answer (score 0):

I believe forevereffort has the answer for your but I just wanted to point out some things related to formatting.

1. `this.` isn't necessary in template s `<tr *ngFor="let item of familyInfo">` is okay.
2. there is really [a difference between](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ygYuD_JRUQk) `value="{{item.name | titlecase}}"` and `[value]="item.name | titlecase"` (you should use the latter.)
3. try to keep css in the `.scss` files